# Skype call notification

Tags: android

How can i receive notification if user is calling from Skype.

Comment: can you specify more... notification when using skype where on the mobile? mobile notification? or a mail?

Comment: when i dial some phone number and press call button then device show me a option from where i can choose to call the number. options are SKYPE or through service provider like Virgin, vodafone. when i choose skype then it call the number through Skype phone.